# Thread Safe Stack Implementation in C++ Using Atomic: Reclaiming nodes when no threads are in pop()

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, stack, atomic

I am trying to run the below code but I am getting the below error intermittently. Could you please let me know what could be the reason for this error.

Error: "Segmentation fault 11"

Code is from C++ ConcurrencyInAction book: Thread Safe Stack Implementation in C++ Using Atomic: Reclaiming nodes when no threads are in pop()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

struct threadlog
{
    void printLog(string tLog)
    {
        cout << tLog << endl;
    }
};

thread_local string thrdName(":M:");
thread_local threadlog thrdLog;

template <typename T>
class lock_free_stack
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        node *next;
        node(T const &data_) : data(std::make_shared<T>(data_))
        {
        }
    };
    std::atomic<node *> head;
    std::atomic<unsigned> threads_in_pop;
    std::atomic<node *> to_be_deleted = nullptr;
    static void delete_nodes(node *nodes)
    {
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":delete_nodes():START");
        while (nodes)
        {
            node *next = nodes->next;
            delete nodes;
            nodes = next;
        }
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":delete_nodes():END");
    }
    void try_reclaim(node *old_head)
    {
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():START");
        if (threads_in_pop == 1)
        {
            thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():threads_in_pop==1");
            node *nodes_to_delete = to_be_deleted.exchange(nullptr);
            if (!--threads_in_pop)
            {
                thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():!--threads_in_pop:delete_nodes()");
                delete_nodes(nodes_to_delete);
            }
            else if (nodes_to_delete)
            {
                thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():nodes_to_delete:chain_pending_nodes()");
                chain_pending_nodes(nodes_to_delete);
            }
            thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():delete old_head");
            delete old_head;
            thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():old_head deleted");
        }
        else
        {
            thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():threads_in_pop>1:chain_pending_node()");
            chain_pending_node(old_head);
            thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():--threads_in_pop");
            --threads_in_pop;
        }
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":try_reclaim():END");
    }
    void chain_pending_nodes(node *nodes)
    {
        node *last = nodes;
        while (node *const next = last->next)
        {
            last = next;
        }
        chain_pending_nodes(nodes, last);
    }
    void chain_pending_nodes(node *first, node *last)
    {
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":chain_pending_nodes():START");
        last->next = to_be_deleted;
        while (!to_be_deleted.compare_exchange_weak(
            last->next, first))
            ;
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":chain_pending_nodes():END");
    }
    void chain_pending_node(node *n)
    {
        chain_pending_nodes(n, n);
    }

public:
    void push(T const &data, string tName)
    {
        thrdName = tName;
        node *const new_node = new node(data);
        new_node->next = head.load();
        while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node))
        {
        }
        cout << (*(head.load()->data)) << "-->";
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop(string tName)
    {
        thrdName = tName;
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":pop():START:++threads_in_pop");
        ++threads_in_pop;
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":pop():getting old_head");
        node *old_head = head.load();
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":pop():old_head:data:" + (*(old_head->data)));
        while (old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next))
        {
            thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":pop():while:old_head:" + (*(old_head->data)));
        }
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":pop():old_head:removed");
        std::shared_ptr<T> res;
        if (old_head)
        {
            thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":pop():res.swap()");
            res.swap(old_head->data);
        }
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":pop():try_reclaim()");
        try_reclaim(old_head);
        thrdLog.printLog(thrdName + ":pop():END");
        return res;
    }
};

int main()
{
    thrdLog = threadlog();
    lock_free_stack<string> lfs;
    vector<thread> ths;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        ths.push_back(thread(&lock_free_stack<string>::push, &lfs, ("data_" + to_string(i)), (":PUSH_T_" + to_string(i) + ":")));
    }
    for (auto &th : ths)
    {
        th.join();
    }
    cout << endl;
    vector<thread> popths;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        popths.push_back(thread(&lock_free_stack<string>::pop, &lfs, (":POP_T_" + to_string(i) + ":")));
    }
    for (auto &th : popths)
    {
        th.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Response:

```
data_2—>data_3—>data_1—>data_4—>data_5
:POP_T_1::pop():START:++threads_in_pop
:POP_T_1::pop():getting old_head
:POP_T_2::pop():START:++threads_in_pop
:POP_T_3::pop():START:++threads_in_pop
:POP_T_3::pop():getting old_head
:POP_T_3::pop():old_head:data:data_5
:POP_T_3::pop():old_head:removed
:POP_T_3::pop():res.swap()
:POP_T_3::pop():try_reclaim()
:POP_T_3::try_reclaim():START
:POP_T_3::try_reclaim():threads_in_pop>1:chain_pending_node()
:POP_T_3::chain_pending_nodes():START
:POP_T_3::chain_pending_nodes():END
:POP_T_3::try_reclaim():--threads_in_pop
:POP_T_3::try_reclaim():END
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: are you sure you really want 33 `#include` !?

Comment: Run you code under a debugger until it segfaults.  The backtrace at the point of the crash should give you a starting point for further investigation.